# How does one get rid of $ p $?

Tags: propositional-calculus

How does one get rid of $ p $ in $(p\Leftrightarrow q) \wedge (p\Leftrightarrow r) $? I have already tried to simplify the formula, applied DeMorgan's laws, etc, but nothing helps. Does anyone know how to deal with this?

Comment: Do you want to prove that $[(p\iff q)\land (p \iff r)]\implies(q\iff r)$? If so, what exactly is at your disposal? Would a truth table suffice?

Comment: What do you mean by "get rid of $p$"? You can certainly prove that the statement you gave implies a certain relationship between $r$ and $q$...

Answer (score 2):

You can't get rid of $p$ without losing some information. However, this does imply that
$$q \iff r,$$
so if you're just looking to remove $p$, that's probably the most informative result.

Comment: But they are not equivalent, their truth tables differ, don't they?

Comment: They aren't equivalent, but the one that you gave implies this one, and I can't see any way to get rid of $p$ that gives you more information about the relationship of $q$ and $r$.